# How to make formula for the fuel consumption in l/100km

Tags: calculus

Hi all can someone help me with this formula that is in this pdf at the beginning.
[LINK](http://www.windmill.co.uk/obdii.pdf) is over here.

I need to get vale in liters per 100km, and not in gallons.

Thank you.

Comment: Liters/100km and gallons are not the same kind of unit. If you mean liters/100km and gallons/mile, then 
$$x\frac{\text{liters}}{\text{100km}}=$$ $$\left(x\frac{\text{liters}}{\text{100km}}\right)\left(y\frac{\text{gal}}{\text{\text{liters}}} \right)  \left(z\frac{\text{100km}}{\text{mile}}\right)\;\frac{\text{gal}}{\text{mile}}$$

Comment: I need formula on the page 4 in the pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a little algebra with the units:

$$\frac{\text{mi}}{\text{gal}}\cdot\frac{\text{km}}{\text{mi}}\cdot\frac{\text{gal}}{\text{litre}}=\frac{\text{km}}{\text{litre}}\;,$$

so

$$\frac1{\frac{\text{mi}}{\text{gal}}\cdot\frac{\text{km}}{\text{mi}}\cdot\frac{\text{gal}}{\text{litre}}}=\frac{\text{litre}}{\text{km}}\;,$$

and

$$\frac{100}{\frac{\text{mi}}{\text{gal}}\cdot\frac{\text{km}}{\text{mi}}\cdot\frac{\text{gal}}{\text{litre}}}=\frac{\text{litres}}{100\text{ km}}\;.$$

There are exactly $1.609344 \dfrac{\text{km}}{\text{mi}}$, and the Google calculator gives a figure of $0.264172052 \dfrac{\text{gal}}{\text{litre}}$, so the conversion factor in the denominator is about $0.4251437$, and the final result is that $$\frac{\text{litres}}{100\text{ km}}\approx\frac{235.214584}{\text{miles per gallon}}\;.$$

Comment: Okay so if I get value for example 30MPG I could use what formula: 30/235.214584 ?

Comment: @denonth: Other way over: $235.214584/30$, or about $7.84$ litres/$100$ km.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more explicit in your question.  The link is quite large and it is not clear what to look at.  It appears you want to convert miles per gallon to liters per 100 km.  The first think to notice is that one is distance/volume and the second is volume/distance, so they will be inverses of each other.  Then convert each unit: 1 mile = 1.609 km = 0.01609 100km; 1 gallon = 3.785 liters.  Your result should look like miles per gallon = A/(liters/100 km).  So A=(mile*liter)/(gallon * 100 km)=0.01609/3.785

Comment: I need formula on the page 4 in the pdf

Comment: Can you give me an example